# Replacing a part of string while keeping the rest intact?

Tags: c#, string, replace, substring

I am making an asp.net web application (with C#) that allows the users to copy/paste their writing and then the application search the content for UK and US conventions for example

in UK car engine room cover is called "bonnet" while in US it is called "hood" so the program will advice the user to change the word from bonnet to hood if he/she is searching for US based conventions (user can switch between UK or US conventions using radio buttons). Conventions are stored in a database.

My question is it is not always "bonnet" or "hood" sometimes the writers use words like "bonnets" or "hoods" so the addition of 's' in the end changes the word completely, how can I change the actual word while keeping the rest intact, like for example bonnets should be changed into hoods (keeping the 's' intact while changed the actual word) ?

Thanks.

Comment: `String.Replace()`? Note that won't work for things where any pre/suffixes aren't the same in both languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you want to detect bonnet(s) with spaces after/before or end/start of the sting.

then I would suggest using Regular expressions.

consider this Regex:
 `(?i)^(.+ )?(bonnet)(s?)( .+)?$`

`(?i)` means case insensitive,

now test this code:

```
string replacedText = Regex.Replace("ssdf bonnets sdf sdf sdf ", @"(?i)^(.+ )?(bonnet)(s?)( .+)?$", "$1hood$3$4");
```

I hope I helped

Comment: Don't look for spaces - check for boundaries (`\b`) instead as those will match non-word characters like `,` or `-` as well. Will also save you from matching stuff before/after (excluding the plural "s").

Comment: Thanks a lot Maziar Taheri, your solution worked exactly as I wanted, String.Equals and String.Contains worked as well but not quiet efficiently because Equals won't look for words like "Pitch(es)" due to that "es" and contains will find unnecessary words like "cell" between Ex(cell)ent but regular expressions detect perfect substrings and also flexible enough to be modified for plurals. Thanks again. Also thanks Mario for boundaries advice.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if(Convention=="UK")
{
  MyString = MyString.Replace("hood","bonnet");
}
else if(Convention=="US")
{
  MyString = MyString.Replace("bonnet","hood");
}
```